# CSS - Fixed background width to stay inside container

Tags: html, css

Is this possible?

Basically I have the following:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="https://bookings.planetbouncetrampolinepark.com/JumpBookings/BookSession.aspx?site=1&amp;group=1">
  <div class="btn-book book-now-merge" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); z-index: 6;">
    <span class="txt-plan" style="display: none;">plan your jump</span>
    <br>
    <span class="txt-book" style="top: -25px; background: url(&quot;/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/txt-book-now.png&quot;);"></span>
    <span id="glim-block" style="height: 0px;">
                                <span class="book-now-glimmer" style="left: 310px; display: block;">
                                </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <span class="book-now-shadow-default" style="display: none;"></span>
  <span class="book-now-shadow" style="display: none; opacity: 0;"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ececec;
}

.book-now-merge {
  background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/book-now-merge.png);
  height: 54px;
  width: 278px;
  background-size: 278px 54px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 73px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xbh3474g/).

I basically always want `.book-now-merge` to always align right of the `#wrapper` div but as a fixed position so it stays with you as you scroll down the page, any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the `#wrapper` and `.book-now-merge` have a fixed width, you can take the width of `#wrapper` (600px), subtract from that the width of  `.book-now-merge`  (278px) and use the resulting `322px` as the `left` parameter of the fixed positioned `.book-now-merge` element:

https://jsfiddle.net/f7wy5vh4/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ececec;
}

.book-now-merge {
  background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/book-now-merge.png);
  height: 54px;
  width: 278px;
  background-size: 278px 54px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 73px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xbh3474g/1/)

Comment: This doesn't move with you as you scroll down the page otherwise I would use absolute positioning

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float:right` to your `<a>` element and remove `right: 0` from .book-now-merge.

EDIT: If you need .book-now-merge inside of wrapper, just add `margin-left: -278px`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbh3474g/6/)